# Why is splitting blocking from non-blocking operations in separate thread pools a better idea, than executing all in one?

Tags: java, multithreading, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I've been reading Play Framework's Documentation about thread pools (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ThreadPools) in Play, but somehow, I can't do the math on some things. Maybe, you could help me out here.

The docs say that the best practice of maintaining peach between blocking and non-blocking calls is to have multiple thread pools, and use one per specific type of operation. In the case of non-blocking operations, the ideal thread pool would execute 1 thread per core, so the maximum of threads would be pretty low. For blocking operations (such as heavy relational DB calls), the better approach is to have a large thread pool that allows for many available threads per core.

Where I don't see the math clicking is, if we imagine that we run the app on a 4-core machine, then the maximum of actively running threads is 4. This means that if 4 threads are occupied with time-consuming DB operations, my non-blocking operations will also have a hard time executing, until the blocking operations are gone.

My question therefore is what is the real benefit of running two separate thread pools, than having one that is moderately large. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

A blocked thread does not block a core.

When a *thread* is blocked, it gives up the core it is running on, making that core available to run another thread. So your non-blocking operations are able to proceed on a different thread if there is one available.

The reason to use separate thread pools is that it is possible that blocking operations can exhaust all the available threads in a pool so that there are none available for non-blocking operations. By using a separate pool for non-blocking operations you can help ensure there are threads available to take advantage of the cores that are not continuously being used by the blocking operations.

Comment: That excludes the case when a thread is executing a local time-consuming CPU operation, right? In this case, a thread does get blocked, but so does its respective CPU core

Comment: The terminology may be a bit confusing. True, this does not include that case, but here the thread itself is not *blocked*, but *running*, in other words it is just busy or long-running. A *caller* might be blocked until the operation is complete, but the thread itself is not blocked. These kinds of operations might as well be handled in the same thread pool as other non-blocking operations, since it does indeed tie up a core as well as a thread.

Comment: Threads that are actually blocked are generally waiting on some kind of I/O such as DB operations as was mentioned, rather than consuming CPU -- and the DB itself is usually running on some other machine or at least in some other process.

Comment: .. and even with an "embedded" DB, the DB itself also generally blocks on disk I/O which will immediately free the core to run another thread.